# File Upload.Go Ahead Webserver

Tags: file-upload, webserver, cgi, embeddedwebserver

Right now, i am working on a go ahead embedded web server. i have an old 2.1 version of this server, which was open source. i want to upload .json file which i create from the firmware, to the web server and then want the page to process that file using flot tool,and display a graph.but that version does not support file uploading capability. on internet i have found that the new version of this web server support the file upload capabilities, but i have not found a proper example which explains the syntax that i would use to upload the file. can any one tell me which functions of this new version i would have to use to get things working.
can any one give a proper full example.

Answer (score 0):

You ask how to upload using goahead.

When you build the source, it should build a test executable called goahead-test. This uses test/test.c as a main program. Test.c defines an upload action handler that is invoked when you do a file upload to the url /action/uploadTest. This handler will echo back to the browser the various file upload details. You can cut/paste from test.c into your own main program.

Comment: brien can you tell me, if i want to take file upload functionality to my project's old goahead 2.1 version. can i do that. beacause i have already done alot of work on that. i am working on blackfin processor and i think that new version is not ported to blackfin processors. if yes then can you tell me how is that possible. which files do i have to take to my project.